# combining multiple greps on to a a perl script

Tags: perl, grep

```
sub logProcessing {
    my $logpath = $File::Find::dir;
    my $logfile = $_;
    if ( $File::Find::name =~ m!$logDir/(.*?)/$pattern! and -d $File::Find::dir ) { $dirCount++ };
    if ( $File::Find::name =~ m!$logDir/(.*?)/$pattern! and -f $File::Find::name ) { $fileCount++ };
    if ( $File::Find::name =~ m!$logDir/(.*?)/$pattern! and -f $File::Find::name ) {
        my $errorsSeen = `grep 'Errno 110' $File::Find::name|uniq`;
        if ($errorsSeen ne "") {
            $errorCount++;
            my $hostname = $1;
            my $lastModTime = localtime ( (stat $File::Find::name)[9] );
            printf FILE "%3s %20s %50s %30s %50s\n", $hostname, 'Errno 110', $logpath, $logfile, $lastModTime;
        }
        else {
            $nullCount++
        }
    }
}
```

The above is a code snippet from a Perl script which actually searches a bunch of log files and does a pattern search and prints a summary and sent it as a mail with attachment.

Wanted to refine the search for 3 patterns and don't want to increase the number of grep statement as the log files are 10k per day and that will increase the runtime of the script which now completes in approx 10 minutes.

As of now it searches 'Errno 110' but wants to add a combination of 'Errno 110', 'Errno 13' & 'Errno 43' and print the summary accordingly and as you see in the printf statement 'Errno 110' is hardcoded.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
#

# program revision 1 - addded error filter
# and added error types 
## Loading Modules

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Time::Piece;
use MIME::Lite;
use File::Slurp;
use Fcntl qw(:flock);
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_ignore_case);

## Generic Variables

my $progversion = "1";
my $progrevision = "1";
my $prog_name = "error_alert.pl";
my $help;
my $version;
my $dryrun;

## Main Program Variables

my $dc = 'IN';
chomp($dc);
my $fileDate = localtime->ymd("-");
chomp($fileDate);
my $logDir = "/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs";
my $Date = localtime->ymd("");
my $pattern = "applmgr\.log\.$Date";
chomp($Date);
chomp($pattern);
my $fileCount = 0;
my $dirCount = 0;
my $errorCount = 0;
my $nullCount = 0;

#my $to = 'ajoy.bharath@XXXXXX';
my $to = '123@xyz.com, 345@xyz.com, xyz@abc.com';
my $from = 'no-reply@xyz.com';
my $subject = "Log Alert ($dc)";
my $subDate = localtime->ymd("/");
chomp($subDate);
my $message = "<h2>Log Processing Status of $dc for Date:- $subDate </h2> <br> <h3>Please find the attached file for stats..!</h3>";
my $outFile = "$logDir/applmgr_status_$dc-$fileDate.txt";

## locking multiple instances of this script

open my $lockFile, ">", "$logDir/script.lock" or die $!; 
flock $lockFile, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB or die "Multiple instance not allowed: $!";
print $lockFile "$$";

## Options Sub Routines

sub print_usage() {
    print "Usage: $prog_name or $prog_name with options [-v|--version] [-h|--help] [-d|--dryrun]\n";
    exit(1);
}

sub print_version() {
    print "$prog_name : $progversion.$progrevision\n";
    exit(0);
}

sub print_help () {
    print "$prog_name : $progversion.$progrevision";
    print "\n";
    print "Usage: $prog_name  or $prog_name with options [-v|--version] [-h|--help] [-d|--dryrun]";
    print "\n";
    print "$prog_name = process logs and process summary and send mail\n";
    print "-v|--version = Version.\n";
    print "-h|--help = This screen.\n";
    print "-d|--dryrun = process logs and process summary and output to stdout instead of sending mail\n\n";
    print "\n";
    exit(0);
}

sub dry_run {
   open(FILE, ">$logDir/applmgr_status_$dc-$fileDate.txt") or die "Cannot open file";
   printf FILE "%3s %20s %30s %40s %50s\n", "Host Name", "Errors", "Log Path", "Log FIle", "Modified Time";
   printf FILE "%3s\n", "-" x 150;
   find( \&logProcessing, $logDir);
   print FILE "\n\nSUMMARY\n";
   printf FILE "%3s\n", "-" x 20;
   print FILE "Number of Hosts investigated for error: $dirCount\n";
   print FILE "Number of LogFiles investigated for error: $fileCount\n";
   print FILE "Number of Hosts processed with errors: $errorCount\n";
   print FILE "Number of Hosts processed wihout errors: $nullCount\n";
   close(FILE);
   my $data = read_file($outFile);
   print $data;
   exit(0);
}

# Main Program starts here

print_usage() if ( ! GetOptions('v|version' => \$version, 'h|help' => \$help, 'd|dryrun' => \$dryrun));
print_help() if ($help);
print_version() if ($version);
dry_run() if ($dryrun);

open(FILE, ">$logDir/applmgr_status_$dc-$fileDate.txt") or die "Cannot open file";
printf FILE "%3s %20s %30s %40s %50s\n", "Host Name", "Errors", "Log Path", "Log FIle", "Modified Time";
printf FILE "%3s\n", "-" x 150;

find( \&logProcessing, $logDir);

print FILE "\n\nSUMMARY\n";
printf FILE "%3s\n", "-" x 20;
print FILE "Number of Podhosts investigated for error: $dirCount\n";
print FILE "Number of LogFiles investigated for error: $fileCount\n";
print FILE "Number of Podhosts harvested with errors: $errorCount\n";
print FILE "Number of Podhosts harvested wihout errors: $nullCount\n";

&alertMessage;

## Main Program Sub Routines

sub logProcessing {
    my $logpath = $File::Find::dir;
    my $logfile = $_;
    if ( $File::Find::name =~m!$logDir/(.*?)/$pattern! and -d $File::Find::dir ) { $dirCount++ };
    if ( $File::Find::name =~m!$logDir/(.*?)/$pattern! and -f $File::Find::name ) { $fileCount++ };
    if($File::Find::name =~m!$logDir/(.*?)/$pattern! and -f $File::Find::name) {
      my $errorsSeen = `grep 'Errno 110' $File::Find::name|uniq`;
      if ($errorsSeen ne "") {
      $errorCount++;
      my $hostname = $1;
        my $lastModTime = localtime ( (stat $File::Find::name)[9] );
        printf FILE "%3s %20s %50s %30s %50s\n", $hostname, 'Errno 110', $logpath, $logfile, $lastModTime;
        } else { $nullCount++ }
    }
}

close(FILE);

sub alertMessage {

  my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                 From     => $from,
                 To       => $to,
                 Subject  => $subject,
                 Type     => 'multipart/mixed'
                 );

  $msg->attach(
             Type  => 'text/html',
             Data  => $message
            );

  $msg->attach(
             Type         => 'text/html',
             Path         => $outFile,
             Disposition  => 'attachment'
   );

  $msg->send;
}
```

==========================================================
sample log file - applmgr.log.20170303

```
2017-03-03 08:35:13 UTC 965 [14385] ERROR upload process failed with: error(110, 'Connection timed out') 
error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out 
2017-03-03 08:43:43 UTC 913 [20057] ERROR upload process failed with: error(110, 'Connection timed out') 
error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out 
2017-05-26 08:10:14 UTC 278 [7665] WARNING Failed to check upload result with: Exception('Received error response 400 Bad Request from HTTP server',) 
2017-05-26 08:10:14 UTC 288 [7665] ERROR upload process failed with: error(32, 'Broken pipe') error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe 
2017-05-26 08:10:14 UTC 278 [7665] WARNING Failed to check upload result with: Exception('Received error response 400 Bad Request from HTTP server',) 
2017-05-26 08:10:14 UTC 288 [7665] ERROR upload process failed with: error(32, 'Broken pipe') error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe 
2017-05-26 08:10:14 UTC 278 [7665] WARNING Failed to check upload result with: Exception('Received error response 400 Bad Request from HTTP server',) 
2017-05-26 08:10:14 UTC 288 [7665] ERROR upload process failed with: error(32, 'Broken pipe') error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe 
2017-03-03 08:29:24 UTC 010 [9417] ERROR upload process failed with: error(110, 'Connection timed out') 
error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Any help in streamlining this for better performance or better logic is much more appreciable. I'm a novice in perl and I appled my logic as it is. My refences were Automating System Administration with perl and questions I've asked and others asked in stack* sites

Comment: I think some sample data and example usage would help. There are no `grep` statements in your code...

Comment: Side note, `my ($matched) = $File::Find::name =~ m!$logDir/(.*?)/$pattern!;` if you care about DRY and performance.

Comment: Checks like `-d $File::Find::dir` and `-f $File::Find::name` are redundant

Comment: updated the input

Comment: `grep -P` accepts perl-like regex as an argument, i.e. `Error\s+(110|13|43)`. Can you use this?